# PXSelector autorefresh isn't working for a custom selector

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom selector attribute that returns different recordsets based on what a user field in the Tasks grid (on the projects screen) is set to.  I have commit changes set to true for the user field, and syncposition=true in the aspx for the grid.  Since the custom selector attribute is added via the TaskCD CacheAttached event, I don't see the AutoRefresh property in the field's property window (see below):

[image]

Is there a way to AutoRefresh in code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to additionally declare input control for the custom column. For reference see screenshots below captured from Step 11.9 of T300 training guide:
[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand how any of that relates to refreshing a PXSelector results page upon opening.  Am I missing something, or did you misunderstand my question?...

Comment: The AutoRefresh property is only available for PXSelector and PXSegmentMask controls. According to your screenshot, selected Task ID node represents grid column (and basically is PXGridColumn). In order to access the AutoRefresh property, you have to follow steps suggested in the previous answer and additionally define input control for the Task ID column

Comment: So in summary for a given field you could have an entry for the column which as Ruslan said is PXGridColumn but then you also have a RowTemplate which is where you need your AutoRefresh to live on your PXSelector or PXSegmentMask. For example look at the sales order page SO301000 and look at the transaction details for "UOM". Personally when I edit pages I never use Acumatica. I edit the page directly under actions > Edit ASPX in the Layout Editor as Ruslan as copied as a screen shot.

Comment: So I can just put AutoRefresh="True" on the PXSegmentMask tag for TaskCD field?

Comment: Just an FYI - I already have this - should this work?  Because it's sporadic.  sometimes it refreshes and sometimes it doesn't.




      <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="Tasks" DataKeyNames="ProjectID,TaskCD">
                                <RowTemplate>
                                    <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" StartColumn="True" LabelsWidth="SM" ControlSize="XM" ></px:PXLayoutRule>
                                    <px:PXSegmentMask AutoRefresh="True" ID="edProjectTaskCD" runat="server" DataField="TaskCD" ></px:PXSegmentMask>